# Spinner with delete button make items disabled

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have an spinner in my activity. I need to show text and delete button when user click the drop down button.

So I wrote Custom Array Adapter and it is render correctly. But I can only click the delete button and it go to delete button on Click event. It is as expect but I cant choose the item anymore when I click the text. All row are disabled except delete button click.

Comment: please put the code that you are using.That might make things easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
//CUSTOM SPINNER ADAPTER
public class CardListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
private Context appContext = null;
private ArrayList<Card> items = null;

public CardListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Card> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.appContext = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) appContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.card_simple_list, null);
    }

    final Card o = items.get(position);
    if (o != null) {

        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_Name);

        if (name != null) {
            name.setText(o.getName());
        }
    }
    return v;

}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) appContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.card_list, null);
    }

    final Card o = items.get(position);
    if (o != null) {

        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_Name);

        ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton) v
                .findViewById(R.id.card_Delete);

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                items.remove(o);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        if (name != null) {
            name.setText(o.getName());
        }
    }
    return v;
}

} // end custom adapter}
```

Comment: Got the answer. I should use the image view instead of ImageButton.

Comment: Mark the question as answered please